# Malformatted joda datetime for http header "last-modified"?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to parse a simple datetime and just getting an exception. Why?

```
DateTimeFormat.forPatter("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.GERMAN)
       .withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime("Fri, 08 Aug 2014 12:32:12 GMT");
```

Result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Fri, 08 Aug 2014 12:32:12 GMT" is malformed at "i, 08 Aug 2014 12:32:12 GMT"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `EEE` instead of just `E` ?

Comment: According to http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html `E = day of week`.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Anyways, using `EEE` gives the same error!

Comment: Oh, and your locale is german - probably "Friday" will become something like "Freitag"

Comment: Would you mind adding this as the answer so I can accept it? `Locale.ENGLISH` works.

Comment: Ok, I've added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example uses `.withLocale(Locale.GERMAN)` which means that not only date fromat itself, but also all related words will be expected to be in German locale.

So `parseDateTime` method will expect not "Friday" and "Fri" but "Freitag" and "Fre" respectivly. I'd suggest you to stick with `Locale.ENGLISH` setting if you want to parse strings like "Fri, 08 Aug 2014 12:32:12 GMT"